# Run node_modules binary on Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm trying to compress an image on Lambda using mozjpeg, but am having some issues.

The binary doesn't have execute permissions, and so I'm getting this error:

```
"exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)",
"ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:298:11)",
"Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)",
"ret.catch.module.exports.promise (/var/task/node_modules/imagemin-mozjpeg/node_modules/exec-buffer/node_modules/execa/index.js:132:26)",
"/var/task/node_modules/imagemin-mozjpeg/node_modules/exec-buffer/index.js:36:15"
```

When I try to fix the permissions, I get this error:

```
 'chmod: changing permissions of ‘/var/task/node_modules/imagemin-mozjpeg/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg’: Read-only file system\n'
```

Is there a way to get the binaries to execute within node_modules, or an alternative to executing them manually from the tmp dir without the benefit of their nodejs wrappers?

Comment: please show your lambda code so we can see how you use this library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the method you use to zip your files includes preserving or setting the execute permissions in Unix format. They will then be preserved when the file is unzipped from S3.